# Notify Raspberry when a new device is connected (USB,SPI,I2C...)

Tags: raspberry-pi, device, daemon

What i´m trying to do is: having a daemon running in the background that notify when a new "wired" device is connected to the raspberry. 
Can anyone help me?

Thanks all!

Comment: What OS are you running? Raspbian?

Comment: yes yes im using Raspbian

Comment: Not sure it is best practice to be attaching SPI and I2C devices while a RaspberryPi is powered up...

Comment: Yeah i know, but right now im focusing in adding usb only. I wrote the following udev rule to notify anytime i plug an usb device: 
`ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/bash /home/pi/device_plug.sh"`
@MarkSetchell

Answer (score 0):

You can check [udev](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev). It's possible to write an udev rule to achieve the behavior. In that way you don't even have to write a daemon.

Comment: I tried the following udev rule: `ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/bash /home/pi/device_plug.sh"`
 But not working... @lebenlechzer